# Cant access firewall in system preferences; firewall tab is greyed out

Tags: macos, permission, preferences, firewall

I have tried multiple things to rememdy this issue. I have tried enabling and logging in as root, tried to clone the system preferences app and accessing security and privacy from the view menu and nothing seems to work. I have repaired permissions from disk utility, repaired permissions through terminal at utility repair and still nothing. I will say that there was a previous user at my machine which I went through the best approach I could find by saving the previous home folder and creating another. My new user is set to administrator also. I am open to any suggestions here as I am fresh out of ideas.

I also made sure to authenticate via the lock icon in system preferences pane.

Im running:
-3.4ghz i7 imac
-16g ram
-osx mavericks 10.9.5
-local network

Update:
*just tried running this in terminal and restarting… also to no avail*
`sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf.plist`

Update:
tried toggling socketfilterfw off and then on through terminal but both times terminal output that the firewall was already in the state I was attempting to set it to.
*still no solution…*

Update:
Im now gearing to wipe and reinstall my os drive. I have run out of things to try and assume that it's a convoluted permissions issue. If anyone has any last-ditch ideas, I'm all ears. Thanks for everyone's help.

Final Update:
I wiped and reinstalled… never got a solution to this one.

Comment: You must have a 3d party app controlling it.

Comment: Something like Anti Virus app, or dreaded Clean my Mac..ect.

Comment: Is there any way to isolate an offender? Ive looked through my app directory and nothing appears to fit that description. _Im not opposed to command line solutions here either._

Comment: Could you improve your OQ please? Could you write if you had this problem since the initial install, since a particular upgrade or since any other event. There are bugs, but they usually don't fall out of the blue sky :).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure when the issue occurred as with most people I would assume, the firewall panel isn't a frequent access item for me. I did attempt to be as thorough as possible with the problem description, known variables and solution attempts. It is a machine I inherited at a job so I don't have it's complete history. So, I suppose what im saying here is if there is a common method to glean that information, I'm more than willing to find it, but at present this is all the information I have unless there is something specific that would help.

Answer (score 2):

My first assumption is that you have a app like Anti Virus that took over the control of your Firewall.

Here is a [article](http://krypted.com/tag/manage-firewall-os-x-command-line/) on using the Terminal commands with Firewall.

It is for Lion, but I assume they still work with Mavericks.

For example to start it:

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setglobalstate on
```

Give it a try.

Comment: terminal returned: `Firewall is enabled. (State = 1)` _still no change for the preference pane_

Comment: Then turn of off and on again in Terminal to overcome who ever is using it.

Comment: `--setglobalstate off` terminal returns: `Firewall is already disabled` When I set it back to on, it outputs the same: `Firewall is enabled. (State = 1)`